# display new row at first row inside dataGrid or focus on the newly added row

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

My requirement is to add a new row at the first row of the grid inside dataGrid on click of **ADD Row** button. I can able to add new row inside grid, but i want to 
add/display new row in the first row of the grid each time when user click Add Row button. Currently when user want to add new row , its been displayed
after the existing rows as can be seen in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/59/.
Please suggest how can i **display the** **new added row in the first row of the existing data grid or if added at the last row as shown in the fiddle, focus on the newly added row by the user**.

Below is the sample code:

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'],

function (lang, DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, Button, dom) {
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
        identifier: "id",
        items: [{
            id : 1,
            col2 : "aa",
            col3 : "bb",
            col4 : "cC"
         }]
    };

    var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [
        [{
            'name': 'Column 1',
                'field': 'id',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 2',
                'field': 'col2',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 3',
                'field': 'col3',
                'width': '200px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 4',
                'field': 'col4',
                'width': '150px'
        }]
    ];

    /*create a new grid*/
    var grid = new DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'
    });

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();

    var id = 2;

    var button = new Button({
        onClick: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
            store.newItem({
                id: id,
                col2: "col2-" + id,
                col3: "col3-" + id,
                col4: "col4-" + id
            });
            id++;
        }
    }, "addRow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `sortInfo` property of the grid to `-1` which will sort the grid by the first column in descending order and force a sort after renderRow with `dojo/aspect`

```
aspect.after(grid, 'renderRow', grid.sort);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/740L0y43/

If possible, use [dgrid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid). `dojox/grid/DataGrid` is or will be deprecated.

Comment: In my project, below javascript error its throwing : TypeError: Cannot read property 'after' of undefined. Can you please suggest can we implement this functionality by writing javascript and scroll to last location/row where the new row is created inside the grid if i have 100 of records in my grid and has scrollbar within grid, thanks. I'm using enhanced grid in my project , http://jsfiddle.net/740L0y43/2/. Ur suggestion is working in fiddle but not in my local project :(

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to require `'dojo/aspect'`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, in my local application i have added  require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/aspect', 'dojo/domReady!']); but still its not working as expected, throwing the error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'after' of undefined. @Richard Ayotte

Comment: Can you post a gist of your code? The require function is made up of two parts. The modules is required the variable that it is assigned to.

Comment: Please see the fiddle, my code looks like the one in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/740L0y43/9/.  Thanks @Richard Ayotte

Comment: There are problems in the fiddle beyond the scope of this question.